# Modify Gradle buildConfigField at compilation time

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm facing an issue when I try to populate `buildConfigField` during compilation time.
For some reason, I have multiple product flavors which haven't the same arguments.
I will simplify as this:
File `flavorA.config`:

```
propertyA=property1
propertyB=property2
propertyC=property3
...
```

File `flavorB.config`:

```
propertyA=property1bis
propertyD=property4
propertyE=property5
...
```

As you can see, A and B shares `propertyA` but others aren't. 
If I put the instruction `buildConfigField (string) (string) (string)` inside `configureEach { flavor -> ... }`, it works well, but it's triggered as soon as I synchronize gradle.

If I put the instruction otherwise:

```
task.register('customTask') { doLast { (here) } }
preBuild.dependsOn customTask
```

The instruction is triggered during compilation time, but `buildConfigField` is unknown here...

Is there a way to populate it during compilation? 
The main purpose is to share only desired variables to developers (for example production), and to be sure CI doesn't know unexpected variables.
Plus, to display a message if there is a variable missing for desired flavor, I don't want to trigger a message for development environment if I'm running production one...

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong when it is done in "synchronize gradle" ?

Comment: @Selvin you are forced to shared unwanted properties, for some reasons, I don't want to share all flavors with everyone, some people are supposed to only access desired flavors properties

Comment: ["synchronize" is a good time](https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/0cf9e0ddce3b1778a9b8bd001f1ce53c)